# Razer Nari headphones do not work wirelessly on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I am able to see the device in my sound menu, I have it set to use that device, but no sound is coming from the headphones. The sound is turned all the way up on the device's physical dial, and the sound is turned all the way up in Ubuntu, and even the mic works, but the sound does not. The sound works fine in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do work, you need to roll the dial on the back from the game icon to the chat icon. However, they only appear to work in mono, so you will not get 3D sound.